# CMS Pages and linking together

Tags: magento-1.8, cms

I have 2 store views, English & French.

I also have 2 CMS pages, the English page being /stores & the French pages being /magasins

Is there any way in the admin to actually link these 2 pages together as currently they are completely separate pages but they are really the same page but translated into a different languages.

Answer (score 2):

You can add url rewrites for them.
Go to Catalog->Url Rewrite Management and add a new url rewrite.
Select `Custom` for `Create URL Rewrite:`.
Then fill in the rest of the fields

```
Store : English
ID Path: Fill in a unique string here
Request Path: magasins 
Target Path: stores
Redirect : Permanent (301)
Description: Not important. You can leave it blank
```

Save.
Then do the same thing again for the other way around.

```
Store : French
ID Path: Fill in a unique string here
Request Path:  stores
Target Path: magasins
Redirect : Permanent (301)
Description: Not important. You can leave it blank
```

Save.

This should be just fine if you have only a few pages in this case. If you have a lot of them it becomes harder to manage.
In this case I recommend you [this extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/CmsRewrites).
It allows you to do the same thing, but from a single screen. You just have to fill in the url keys for each page in each language and it will create the url rewrites on a single click.

---

<sub>I'm the extension developer, but the extension is free and I get not financial benefits from it. So this should not be considered as spam.</sub>